# Count Number of Occurrences Per Hour From DateTime Start/Stop

Tags: python, datetime, group-by, count, pivot

First time posting so hopefully this isn't a duplicate - if it is please let me know if it is, since I've spent the past few days in search of a method to do what I want.

So I have a very large set of data, which has two columns of interest - a "session_start" and "session_end":

```
          session_start          session_end   group
0   2018-01-03 00:00:00  2018-01-03 00:00:14   1
1   2018-01-03 00:00:00  2018-01-03 00:26:58   2
2   2018-01-03 00:00:00  2018-01-03 00:00:12   1
...
16  2018-01-03 00:00:00  2018-01-03 00:46:07   6
17  2018-01-03 00:00:00  2018-01-03 00:00:18   2
18  2018-01-03 00:00:00  2018-01-03 00:00:08   4
19  2018-01-03 00:00:00  2018-01-03 00:00:06   2
```

What I'd like to do is "convert" this from a start-stop dataset to counting the number of occurrences per hour (or half-hour), and get a portion of the hour (or half-hour) where exists. For example, in row 1 above, 00:00:00 - 00:26:58 would count as 0.449 for 12:00am-1:00am. A row that is 05:32:45 - 07:12:33 would be a portion of 5:00am-6:00am, all of 6:00am-7:00am, and a portion of 7:00am-8:00am. This would be summed up per hour, per day, for 365 day out of the year, grouped by several variables and have an output like this:

```
session_time_hr     grp1_ct    grp2_ct ...
2018-01-01 00:00    45.6       42
2018-01-01 01:00    52         132
2018-01-01 02:00    33         1
...
```

So far I've only seen it done only based on day ranges and even then the logic was fuzzy at best.

I saw this post and I'm thinking of the same logic but strictly in Python: https://powerpivotpro.com/2013/04/counting-active-rows-in-a-time-period-guest-post-from-chris-campbell/

I'm also looking at the datetimerange library (https://pypi.org/project/DateTimeRange/) but it seems to only give true/false whether a datetime is within a range, not the proportion of the range.